# How to fix the Dockerfile CMD error? As I am trying to create an apache server on ubuntu image

Tags: docker

This is my Docker file

```
FROM ubuntu 
RUN apt-get update 
RUN apt-get install –y apache2 
RUN apt-get install –y apache2-utils 
RUN apt-get clean 
EXPOSE 80 CMD [“apache2ctl”, “-D”, “FOREGROUND”]
```

This is the error I get

```
Step 6/6 : EXPOSE 80 CMD ["apache2ct1","-D","FOREGROUND"]
Invalid containerPort: CMD
```

Comment: You're missing a line break.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`EXPOSE` does not provide `CMD` itself, `CMD` is a separate parameter in Docker file syntax. With that been said your Dockerfile should be like this:

```
FROM ubuntu 
RUN apt-get update 
RUN apt-get install –y apache2 
RUN apt-get install –y apache2-utils 
RUN apt-get clean 
EXPOSE 80 
CMD [“apache2ctl”, “-D”, “FOREGROUND”]
```

Comment: I think it's just a mistake. No need an explanation.